How to persist full screen mode when navigating between pages in a multi-page web application?
I'm working on a multi-page web application where users can enter full screen mode using a button:

However, when users navigate to another page within the application (for example, the Sensors page), the full screen mode resets.
I want to implement a feature where the full screen mode persists across page transitions.
Here's what I've tried so far:

Used document.fullscreenElement and document.exitFullscreen() to enter and exit full screen mode.
Utilized localStorage to store the full screen state, but encountered issues with restoring the state on page load. (It just not worked)

I'm seeking guidance on how to achieve this functionality effectively.
Are there any best practices or recommended approaches for maintaining full screen mode across page changes in a multi-page web application?
Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

It might work if you change the second window listener's type to listen focus event window.addEventListener('focus', () => ...)

It is also not working.

With F11 you can enter full screen in the browser (at least for Chrome), therefore if you replicate the event that is toggled via F11 you would possibly have persistent full screen throughout the whole website.
Check out this other question's top answer as it describes the above, but in code.

So, this will work only on Chrome or any other specific browser, right?

Should be for available for any chromium based browser, and based off of the highest rated answer in the linked question: "This is now possible in the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox and IE(11)."
I can confirm that it works in Brave as well, if you can test it on Safari and Opera you should be good to go.
